# how to recover a git commit mistake

Tags: git, gitlab

Suggestion would be of good help.
I have 2 files in git repo  1.yaml and 2.yaml.
7ceda62 -> Good version of 1.yaml and 2.yaml

1. 2d1f43 -> first commit for that file. In this commit unfortunately I override all the 1.yaml file content to 2.yaml. Both became same here. (ie)2.yaml is incorrect from here onwards
2. 317724 -> Second commit for that file. this commit , others made commit in 2.yaml.
3. e592af -> final commit for that file. this commit , others made commit in 2.yaml.

Note: 1.yaml is always good. 2.yaml got corrupted from 2d1f43. How to easily recover my 2.yaml put back all 3 changes.

what I though is drop the first commit , Manually merge back the first commit changes then cherry-pick the commit 2 and commit 3 to resolve. let me know if there is a better way.

Comment: Interactive rebase and `drop` that commit. You probably will have to resolve conflicts.

Comment: In what order are the commits? Why would one not notice the wrong file while making changes? How similar are the files? If they are similar enough, interactive rebase or reset + cherry-pick _could_ work (no guarantees though)

Comment: Thank you. 1) 2) 3) is the order of commits. (ie) (1) or 2d1f43 (first commit) , 2) is the second commit 317724 , e592af(third).  This is a large file and content looks bit similar so people missed and made changes on top of it. I thought of resetting the first commit then manually put back first commit changes then cherry-pick the commit 2 and commit 3 to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Below operations helped to me recover the issue. I have to resolve conflict in step 3 and 7. Thank you all for the suggestions.

1. git reset --hard 7ceda62
2. Manually added the changed for this commit 2d1f43
3. git cherry-pick -n 317724
4. git add
5. git commit -m"put back changes of 317724"
6. git checkout . (To discard other file changes)
7. git cherry-pick -n e592af
8. git add
9. git commit -m"put back changes of e592af"
   10)git checkout . (To discard other file changes)